# Android Qualcomm BoostFramework()

Tags: android, qualcomm

Quite often I am receiving this kind of message in my `logcat` monitor:

```
12-13 06:09:57.819 25049-25049/? V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@9759349
```

Can someone explain what does it mean and what is triggering the `BoostFramework()` function?

Thanks.

Comment: Not even a single answer lol

Answer (score 8):

Just stumbled upon this unanswered question. BoostFramework is a vendor library provided by Qualcomm for phones using their chips. It allows system components (and applications which implement their API) to temporarily boost the CPU frequency for increased processing power, e.g. when the camera is taking a picture.

Since you are probably not dealing with system code, you can ignore it.

Comment: Not only boost cpu , include some other boost functions.